# TouchXML alive or dead

Tags: iphone, xml, touchxml

Is TouchXML still available?  I cannot find an updated download source, either very old or 404 URL not found???

Is it no longer available?

Answer (score 6):

I believe https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Consider instead using apple's official [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for your XML needs.

Comment: True, but I have read stats that show NSXMLParser is a lot slower than TouchXML, kissXML etc....